# How to write a C or Java application to handle TCP SYN requests

Tags: java, c, sockets, network-programming

I want to handle TCP SYN requests from users to denied some invalid requests to web server (Apache) on a CentOS server

How to write an application in C++ or Java or any programming languages?

Comment: Did you feel deprived of using ``iptables``? And what exact TCP connections (rules) you would like to accept or deny?

Comment: @MohithReddy, i cannot use iptables because my rules are quite complicated. It use database for controlling requests

Answer (score 1):

You can create a netfilter kernel module (in C language), and hook yourself for various packet events such as receiving a packet on a particular interface etc. You will need to check the packet header to figure out whether it is a TCP SYN request, and then decide what to do with it.

https://www.netfilter.org/

You cannot create a user mode C++ or Java program to achieve this.

That being the answer for what you are asking, perhaps a better alternative would be to add rules to the firewall depending on what invalid requests you want to disable.